# instamojo wordpress plugin not working

Tags: wordpress, plugins, payment, instamojo

I am using Wordpress 4.2, and I am looking to use *instamojo* as the payment gateway, so I added this plugin. When I try to create short codes, it showing fatal errors.

Can any one help on this issue?

see the error bellow

> **Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Error in listing all offers.' in
>   /home4/ltzone/public_html/directory-listing/wp-content/plugins/instamojo/lib/Instamojo.php:274
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home4/ltzone/public_html/directory-listing/wp-content/plugins/instamojo/option.php(243):
>   Instamojo->listAllOffers() #1 [internal function]:
>   Instamojo_Settings_Page->create_admin_page('') #2
>   /home4/ltzone/public_html/directory-listing/wp-includes/plugin.php(496):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #3
>   /home4/ltzone/public_html/directory-listing/wp-admin/admin.php(226):
>   do_action('settings_page_i...') #4
>   /home4/ltzone/public_html/directory-listing/wp-admin/options-general.php(10):
>   require_once('/home4/ltzone/p...') #5 {main} thrown in
>   /home4/ltzone/public_html/directory-listing/wp-content/plugins/instamojo/lib/Instamojo.php on line 274**

Comment: Open up wp-config.php scroll down there will be 'WP_DEBUG', set it to true and then post your results here..

Comment: Considering there is no documentation about this plugin I think you'll have better chance to [contact directly the author plugin](https://github.com/rishimukherjee/instamojo-wordpress-plugin/issues). It seems it has not been updated since 2013, so maybe it's not compatible with WP 4.2.

Comment: Hi, I work for Instamojo. The plugin you're using is not supported by us anymore, please switch to our other plugin that works with WooCommerce and allows you to use Instamojo as payment gateway in WordPress: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-instamojo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me give you a clear idea about adding instamojo plugin to woocommerce. Try to follow these steps after deleting the current plugin, as it helps to setup your gateway from scratch:

- Firstly you should have your instamojo's account ready and its plugin installed in your wordpress site.
- Open your Instamojo account's **home** page.
- In home page of your account, go to **API & Plugins**.
- Scroll down this page, you will find a **Generate Fields** section, there select **Woocommerce/Wordpress**
- Copy **Client ID** and **Client Secret** temporarily into a text file.
- Open your Wordpress admin panel and go to **Woocommerce**.
- In **Settings** select **Payments**.
- Go for **Instamojo**.
- Inside it, Enable instamojo.
- Copy Client ID and Client Secret from the temporary text file into the respective fields.
- Save your changes, and payment gateway for your site is ready.